# Play framework 2.6 Database Inject

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm migrating a old project from play 2.4 to 2.6 and now I'm facing some problems to deal with dependency injection

In this case before when we used the `import play.api.db.DB` we can use `DB.withTransaction` but now its not possible, I tried to Inject `db: Database` to my class but I have no effect to use the `db` in my trait.

```
class Device (
  val id:String,
  val secret:String,
  val name:Option[String]) extends DeviceBehavia {

  override def hashCode(): Int = id.hashCode

  override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = obj match {
    case obj:Device => obj.id == this.id
    case _ => false
  }
}

object Device extends DeviceBuilder {
}

trait DeviceBehavia {
  self : Device =>

  def insert():Device = {
    db.withTransaction { implicit c =>
      SQL(
        """
         insert into device(id, secret)
         values ({id}, {secret})
        """
      ).on('id -> id, 'secret -> secret).execute()

      platformInfo.insertWithConnection(this)
      this
    }
  }
}
```

what's the right way to add the dependency Injection like @Inject () (db: Database) to this class and be able to use it on my trait, thank you in advanced.

Comment: `def db: DB` implemented by subclass using DI

Comment: @cchantep thank you but In this case I have 2 problems, 1 - my class need to be abstract "class Device needs to be abstract, since method db in trait DeviceBehavia of type => play.api.db.Database is not defined" and 2 - object creation impossible, since method db in trait DeviceBuilder of type => play.api.db.Database is not defined

Comment: ,which is consistent

Comment: @cchantep but this way my class can't br instantiated :(

Comment: either you need the `Database` instance, or not, but it cannot appear magically.